# How do I create user-defined sql functions using CakePHP?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, create-function

Consider the example given on [this page about creating user-defined functions in SQL and then using the user-defined function in the WHERE clause](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0201__Procedure-Function/Useuserdefinedfunctioninwhereclause.htm).

```
mysql> CREATE FUNCTION myFunction(in_rep_id INT)
    ->      RETURNS INT
    ->      READS SQL DATA
    -> BEGIN
    ->      DECLARE customer_count INT;
    ->
    ->      SELECT COUNT(*)
    ->           INTO customer_count
    ->        FROM employee
    ->       WHERE id=in_rep_id;
    ->
    ->      RETURN(customer_count);
    ->
    -> END$$

mysql> SELECT id,myFunction(id)
    ->   FROM employee
    ->  WHERE myFunction(id)>0
    ->  ORDER BY myFunction(id) desc;
```

How do I replicate this using CakePHP? Do I need to define the function as part of a CakePHP Model? Or is there a way to execute the CREATE FUNCTION syntax but from within CakePHP?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The `CREATE FUNCTION` syntax is really DDL (data definition language) and, like other DDL syntax (e.g. `CREATE TABLE`), isn't supported by Cake. You can *execute* a function via `$this->Model->query( 'your sql here' )`, I suspect, though I've never needed to try it.

I should add that you can really run any arbitrary SQL via the `Model::query()` method, but I made an assumption that this is something you want in place in the same way you want a table in place before it's ever actually needed.

Comment: Many thanks Rob. I guess I'll have to create the function I want directly in SQL and execute the function from within Cake.